# Validation never works

Tags: laravel

I created Request class with validation rules :

```
class RegistrationRequest extends Request{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'number' => 'required|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/',
          'test' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

But Validation never works in a controller.:

```
public function register(RegistrationRequest $request)

  return false;
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? How do you validate that it does not work? You can register successfully? Can you share your blade view, how do you print the errors?

Comment: i dont print errors, i use ajax requests only.

Comment: so can you share your AJAX code?

Comment: no i cant because i use postman for test

Comment: so what is the postman response, you should have a status code and response message, share something so we can know what is going on. This is not enough information that you are sharing. 
If it is a post request, make sure that you are passing a `_token` is all I can say blindly.

Comment: i get 404 response code, if i use FormRequest instead of Request

Answer (score 2):

You should include `FormRequest` in your Request Class

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegistrationRequest extends FormRequest{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'number' => 'required|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/',
          'test' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation